# Bluetooth A2DP API Support on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, bluetooth

I wanna make some iPhone Application which support A2DP and can read sms for car drivers automatically.

I already developed android version but I don't know how to handle A2DP on iOS.
I researched it on wikipedia and I found that from iOS 3.0, it support Bluetooth A2DP like below.

New Developer APIs(iOS 3.0)
    Push notifications for 3rd party applications
    **Bluetooth services including A2DP**, LDAP, P2P file sharing, and BonjourP2,P3,T2,T3
    ...

Is there anyoon who can help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I have developed lots of Android/iOS apps support Bluetooth classic or BLE communication with smart devices recently.

**In Android:**

> ***It's very easy for you to deal with A2DP,you can directly connect the A2DP Profile of the device in Android device.***

**But in iOS,at the present time:**

*The biggest problem is that the first step you need to connect the A2DP profile of the device,and then the audio stream is automatic,unless you need to control the details of A2DP operation.*

> ***NORMALLY,it's very difficult for you to connect the A2DP Profile of the device directly,you need to go to the system settings,find and connect
>   the specific Bluetooth device.But this is really bad for the user
>   experience,the users really don't know why they must do this!***

If you want to connect the A2DP Profile of the device directly in iOS in your app,these methods will help you:

*1.You can tell the users to connect the specific Bluetooth device in iOS system settings,but this is very bad for the user experience.*

*2.Apple doesn't provide the public API for you to deal with A2DP in iOS,I have ever asked the Apple official for support,they told me that there was no way to do this,they didn't tell me why they didn't support this and when would support this.*

*3.You can use the private API to deal with A2DP connection in iOS,if you will not publish your app in App Store,this is very useful.But if you want to publish your app in App Store,this is very dangerous,Apple probably will reject your app,if you really want to do this,you must improve your technical skill of using private API in iOS to prevent from rejection.*

*4.If you or your workmate work on the Bluetooth device that you want to connect,the firmware engineer can help you to do some optimization of the A2DP connection with iOS device.First you need to connect the A2DP of the device in system Bluetooth settings and then the the device can got the link key,and then,if the users don't cancel the A2DP pairing information in system Bluetooth settings,the device can directly connect the A2DP of iOS device.*

*5.You can have a try with MFi,when you device is MFi certificated,maybe you can get more technical support about A2DP connection.I have heard about this from someone,but I did't have a try.*